# tower of hanoi output

Tags: java, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Can someone please tell me why I keep getting 4 when n=2 and 11 when n=3? I should be getting 3 and 7 respectively but its not happening and its very frustrating.

move is a class level static int variable

```
public String solve(int n, String start, String middle, String end) {

     if (n == 1) {
        move++;
        return Integer.toString(move);
     }

     solve(n - 1, start, end, middle);
     move++;
     return solve(n - 1, middle, start, end);
}
```

Comment: Depends on what the initial value of move is.

Comment: Working properly for me. Initially `move` should be `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `move` is static variable and since you are not resetting it before every call so it's next time when you call `solve` method, your move method is not at initial stage i.e. `0`  hence you have to reinitialize it after every call to `solve` method.

Your code is perfectly fine the problem is happening when you are calling your method without resetting the move variable.

Check here: https://ideone.com/NoFJ8y

```
Success time: 0.05 memory: 4386816 signal:0
3 --> When called solve with n=2

Success time: 0.04 memory: 4386816 signal:0
7 --> When called solve with n=3

Success time: 0.04 memory: 4386816 signal:0
3 --> When called solve 3 times  with n=2 then 3 then 4
10
25
```

Comment: Or, make `move` an instance variable, and create a new instance of the class every time you want to solve. As ever, global mutable state is an unnecessary evil.

Comment: @AndyTurner true anything will suffice until `solve` method gets `move` variable in initial stage

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying. When I click the link I am not completely sure what I'm looking for. It just shows the code I have and I am still getting 4 and 11 unfortunately, even if I change move to a non static variable

Comment: @kprog Check now I am resetting move before every call and you get the desired result https://ideone.com/NoFJ8y

Comment: I see now, thank you, I gave marked your answer as correct